# Como definir una fecha como Variable en apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy pasando un archivo de Excel a Google Sheets y tengo un problema con las macros
En excel para definir una variable en VBA se pone así:

```
Dim fecha As Date
```

Pero en Apps Script no sé como debo definir esa variable

Mi código de VBA es así:

```
Sub GUARDAR_FLUJO_DESPACHO()

Sheets("Hoja1").Select
Range("A1").Select

Dim fecha As Date

fecha = Application.Sheets("Corte").Range("C12").Value

If fecha = #12/1/2023# Then
'    
     ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Copy
     ActiveSheet.Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("A1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Corte").Select

Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "Guardado con Exito."

else

End If

 End Sub
```

Ese código quiero pasarlo a Apps Scripts pero cuando pongo la fecha no importa que fecha ponga me sale que es incorrecta y yo pienso que es por el

Comment: Y tú código de apps script?

Comment: En este caso la etiqueta [tag:vba] no aplica porque la pregunta no es sobre VBA, sino sobre Google Apps Script / JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Para declarar una variable llamada `fecha` en Google Apps Script / JavaScript, es opicional usar `var`, `let` o `const`, luego el nombre de la variable. Si usas `const` debes asignarle el valor.

Ejemplos:

Declaración de variable en el ámbito global:

```
fecha;
```

Declaración de variable en el ámbito local:

```
let fecha;
```

Declaración de variable usando `const` y asignando un objeto de fecha:

```
const fecha = new Date(2024,0,24);
```

Nota en JavaScript los meses usan índice base 0, es decir, el índice para enero es 0, para febrero es 1 y así sucesivamente.

---

Si cuentas con una cuenta de Google Workspace Enterprise Plus o una cuenta de Google Workspace for Education Plus podrías usar el complemento "Macro Converter". Si tienes una de estas cuentas, lo primero que debes saber es que en Google Apps Script el lenguage de programación que se utiliza es JavaScript.

No trates de traducir el código VBA a Google Apps Script línea por línea. Primero entiende que hace el código y luego escribo el código de nuevo usando Google Apps Script/JavaScript.

Esto porque hay diferencias importantes, por ejemplo, en JavaScript a las variables no se les asigna un tipo de dato.